# How do you execute Vhosts via PHP?

Tags: php, linux, apache, command-line, virtualhost

I am creating a website where each of the users can point an A record of their domain at my server and I will serve up their web page for them. I know how to do it by Linux command-line, but I am not sure how to do it in a script. I know that `mkdir(/*file location*/)` executes the `mkdir` command. I also know `fopen`. My method is http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/Ubuntu_-_Apache_Virtual_Hosts . I am not exactly positive how to create the custom vhosts etc. by a PHP script.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: DO you wish to serve all requests or specific domains?

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee Only specific domains that they specify.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you are hoping to alter the Apache configuration files using a php script. It is a bit dangerous to do this because you always risk misconfiguring your Apache config file(s) in a way that will prevent Apache from restarting, but I assume that is obvious to you.

I suggest that you use an [include directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include) to a directory where you will be adding and removing individual conf files per vhost.

```
Include conf/vhosts/*.conf
```

(Paths in the include directive are relative to the ServerRoot.) That way you can keep things a little more organized and reduce the possibility of a race condition.

Also you should probably write some code in your script that checks the output of running an [apachectl configtest](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/configuring.html#syntax) command:

```
$ /usr/sbin/apachectl -t
Syntax OK
```

executing it through one of the various PHP [shell/"Program" execution functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) and if there is an error, revert the conf file you just altered.

If you like `fopen`, then use it, but many find the [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) functions easier to work with.

Hope this helps.